# How to change the icon color set in tablayout in android

Tags: android, android-tablayout, android-tabs, android-viewpager2, android-icons

I'm trying to implement tabslayout with text and icons above.
The desired output is this

[image: Desired Output]

But im getting this output

[image: Actual Output]

All those icons have changed color, i'm setting the title and icon programmatically. Code:

```
class HomePage : BaseActivity() {

private lateinit var binding: ActivityHomePageBinding
private lateinit var viewpager: ViewPager2

private val fragmentList = arrayListOf(FoodFragment(),ExerciseFragment(),MedicineFragment(),MoodFragment(),NotesFragment())
private val tabTitles = arrayListOf("Food","Exercise","Medicine","Mood","Notes")
private val tabIcons = arrayListOf(R.drawable.ic_food,R.drawable.ic_exercise,R.drawable.ic_medicine,R.drawable.ic_mood,R.drawable.ic_notes)

private lateinit var customPagerAdapter: CustomPagerAdapter
private lateinit var tablayout: TabLayout

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_home_page)
    initUI()
}

private fun initUI(){

    val bottomSheetDialog = BottomSheetDialog(this)
    val bottomSheetView = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.bottom_modal_sheet,
        findViewById<ConstraintLayout>(R.id.BMS)
    )
    bottomSheetDialog.setContentView(bottomSheetView)

    viewpager = bottomSheetView.findViewById(R.id.BMS_viewpager)
    tablayout = bottomSheetView.findViewById(R.id.BMS_tab_layout)

    customPagerAdapter = CustomPagerAdapter(fragmentList,this)
    viewpager.adapter = customPagerAdapter

    TabLayoutMediator(tablayout, viewpager) { tab, position ->
        tab.text = tabTitles[position]
        tab.setIcon(tabIcons[position])
    }.attach()

    binding.AHPButton.setOnClickListener {
        bottomSheetDialog.show()
    }

}
```

I would really appreciate if someone help me get the original color of the icons im setting.

Also how to change the icon size?

Edit 1: The icon is working fine in imageview, its greyed out in tabsitem for some reason. These icons are svg files. Does that have to do anything with the issue i'm facing? Adding the image for reference. [image]

Comment: Try with this-https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41021677/tablayout-set-custom-color-for-each-tab

Answer (score 2):

Okay so in tabslayout in xml file, i set the `app:tabIconTint="@null"` and it showed me the icons properly.

Answer (score 0):

You can change text and icon using `tabSelectListener`. In  `onTabSelected` you will get the selected tab and in `onTabUnselected` you will get unselected tab. You can have 2 list one that have drawables for selected state and one for unselected state.

```
private val tabIconsSelected = arrayListOf(R.drawable.ic_food_sel,R.drawable.ic_exercise_sel,R.drawable.ic_medicine_sel,R.drawable.ic_mood_sel,R.drawable.ic_notes_sel)
private val tabIconsUnselected = arrayListOf(R.drawable.ic_food_unsel,R.drawable.ic_exercise_unsel,R.drawable.ic_medicine_unsel,R.drawable.ic_mood_unsel,R.drawable.ic_notes_unsel)

 tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                    tab.setIcon(tabIconsSelected[tab.getPosition()]);
                }
    
                @Override
                public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                    tab.setIcon(tabIconsUnselected[tab.getPosition()]);
                }
    
                @Override
                public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
    
                }
            });
```

**Second approach could be you use by declaring  `selected` and `unselected` state in xml file**. Lets name this xml as `custom_food_selector.xml`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_food_sel"
            android:state_selected="true"/>
        <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_food_unsel"
            android:state_selected="false"/>
    </selector>
```

**Add the custom tab selector drawable as the icon for tabItem**.

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/footer"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/female_colour">

        <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
            android:id="@+id/tab_home"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/_25dp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/_25dp"
            android:padding="@dimen/_4dp"
            android:icon="@drawable/custom_food_selector"
            />
 </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>
```

Comment: I've tried that, my issue is the tabsitem is changing the icon, its working fine in imageview. I've edited the question, check it out. Icons are svg files. Does that have to do anything with the output?

Comment: it has default color change it using `android:drawableTint` in your tabItem.

Comment: There is no property `android:drawableTint` in tabItem

Comment: Also the ontabselectedlistener is deprecated